# android instrumentation: need to simulate a button click

Tags: button, click, system, simulate, android-instrumentation

The only issue is that the button resides in the com.android.systemui package, or so I imagine. It is the OK button that a user has to press in order to allow adb over USB. My touchscreen is dead, and I am controlling the phone through an USB mouse, so I am unable to click that OK button to enable debugging (non rooted phone). I was thinking that an instrumentation apk would do it, but... there goes trouble.

Another approach I have taken has been signing the instrumentation .apk with systemui's certificate. That has only led to Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_INSTALL_LOCATION] though.

So, any way to click that button ?

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was to root my phone via kingroot apk, then install a wifi adb apk which, as it says, enabled adb over wifi andI was able to use the OTG mouse in order to accept that dialog asking for permission to adb into the phone.